# How to know for sure that error has occurred in batch after running non batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, aws-cli

I am working with a third party tool AWS CLI which is used to create resources in AWS.
I know of a concept called as `ERRORLEVEL` in batch that if an error occurs while running normal batch commands then `ERRORLEVEL` is set to a `non zero` value.

Now my question is : is there any sure shot way to know that an error has occurred after running AWS cli commands which is clearly not commands of windows batch ? because `ERRORLEVEL` doesn't seem to work or at least i can't make it work for my case. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

CMD's commands and any program can set an EXIT code (which becomes an errorlevel). So your program doesn't do it.

State your problem not instead of asking why your solution doesn't work.

**From Help**

```
ExitProcess
```

Ends the calling process and all its threads.

```
VOID WINAPI ExitProcess(
  UINT uExitCode
);

Parameters
uExitCode 
[in] The exit code for the process and all threads. 
Return Value
This function does not return a value.
```

Comment: i am kind of confused, is it `powershell` or `cmd` ?

Comment: Neither. It is an API call programs make. It is what programs call to exit. If you can't detect an errorlevel, then the program doesn't set one. Some programs write to standard error,and / or set error levels. But graphical programs (ie non console) tend not to do either,